# Goroutines don't scale linearly but Go programs do?

Tags: go

I'm looking for some general advice on optimizing for performance.

I have a rather complex bit of code, but the code lives in a function (no globals), so I can either a) call this function in multiple goroutines (I have 12 cores on my machine). Or b) use the same kind of function called once, compile my go program and run the whole thing 4 times in parallel.

Here is an example code with the same behaviour:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

const size = 140000

type BigStruct struct {
    first  []int
    second []int
}

func slowFunc() int {
    // make local variables
    sum := 0
    myData := BigStruct{}
    myData.first = make([]int, 0, size)

    // fill some slices 
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        myData.first = append(myData.first, i)
        myData.second = append(myData.second, i)
    }

    // do pointless calculations
    for i := range myData.first {
        for j := range
            myData.second {
            if myData.first[i] == myData.second[j] {
                sum++
            }
        }

    }
    return sum
}

func slowFuncChan(output chan int) {
    // make local variables
    sum := 0
    myData := BigStruct{}
    myData.first = make([]int, 0, size)

    // fill some slices 
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        myData.first = append(myData.first, i)
        myData.second = append(myData.second, i)
    }

    // do pointless calculations
    for i := range myData.first {
        for j := range
            myData.second {
            if myData.first[i] == myData.second[j] {
                sum++
            }
        }

    }
    output <- sum
}

func main() {

    numCPUs := runtime.NumCPU()
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(numCPUs)
    fmt.Println("numCPUs: ", numCPUs)

    fmt.Println("Calling slowFunc once...")

    start := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("sum: ", slowFunc())
    t := time.Now() // test
    elapsed := t.Sub(start)
    fmt.Println("time elapsed: ", elapsed)
    fmt.Println()


    fmt.Println("Calling slowFunc 4x in goroutines...")

    output := make(chan int, 4)
    for w := 0; w < 4; w++ {
        go slowFuncChan(output)
    }

    for a := 0; a < 4; a++ {
        fmt.Println("sum: ", <-output)
    }

    t2 := time.Now() // test
    elapsed = t2.Sub(t)
    fmt.Println("time elapsed: ", elapsed)
}
```

When I use 4 goroutines, it takes about 2x as long and running the compiled program in 4x in parallel! And 4 copies of the program running in parallel seem to run only a bit slower than a single running version, i.e. very good scaling.

This is the output from a single program:

```
numCPUs:  12
Calling slowFunc once...
sum:  140000
time elapsed:  10.8093226s
Calling slowFunc 4x in goroutines...
sum:  140000
sum:  140000
sum:  140000
sum:  140000
time elapsed:  22.4335858s
```

Using a batch file, I start up the program 4 times simultaneously, and I get these 4 results:

```
numCPUs:  12
Calling slowFunc once...
sum:  140000
time elapsed:  12.7615683s
```

,

```
numCPUs:  12
Calling slowFunc once...
sum:  140000
time elapsed:  12.7705668s
```

,

```
numCPUs:  12
Calling slowFunc once...
sum:  140000
time elapsed:  12.2635664s
```

,

```
numCPUs:  12
Calling slowFunc once...
sum:  140000
time elapsed:  12.1155655s
```

The total time of running 4 simultaneous programs is 12.7705668s and is nearly half the time of the goroutines version (22.4335858s)

I have tested this out with 8 goroutines vs 8 simultaneous programs, and got the same result, with the multiple apps running 2x the single goroutine version.

Comment: How are you measuring the time to execute the two scenarios?

Comment: If your function truly does not access shared data and does no IO, and does not launch further goroutines, 4 goroutines should complete roughly under the same time. It's impossible to help you further without seeing your code that behaves otherwise. Launching your app 4 times (with 1 goroutine each) have lots of overhead and should perform worse.

Comment: @Cerise The function call takes about 1.5 seconds, so I print a naive difference in time.Now() to get an estimate.

Comment: @icza There is a large struct I load up at the beginning of the function (1mb), but after that, no disk IO.

Comment: @DavidNg That also suggests that a single app with 4 goroutines should perform better (one-time loading that big struct is enough). We should really see something of your code, or come up with a [mcve].

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: @icza Code is here: https://play.golang.org/p/q-zb2LE6381

Comment: @DavidNg Yes, thanks. I've already voted to reopen the question.